# Не отображается результат действия функции append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, chrome-extension

В расширении Chrome, `append` не хочет отображаться на странице, хотя и выводится `alert`

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
   $('body').append('<div class="addNews"><b>Код</b> встроен</div>');
   alert($('body').text());
});
```

Comment: Css свой проверяй.

Comment: Даже в простой странице не отображается 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Пример веб-страницы</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Заголовок</h1>
  <!-- Комментарий -->
  <p>Первый абзац.</p>
  <p>Второй абзац.</p>
 </body>
</html>
Но на экран выводит Код встроен

Comment: Не знаю насчет расширений, а просто по клику на `document` всё работает в [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b6dgnmah/).

Comment: но в самом расширении это не работает.

Comment: А, стоп. Я не заметил, что речь про расширение. У него же своя собственная страница, ты с ней и работаешь. А не с тем, что в браузере открыто.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается проблема была в файле manifest.json
Скрипт для изменения содержания страницы script.js был добавлен в background, то есть работал на странице самого расширения

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["js/jquery.js", "js/script.js"]
}
```

А для работы с открытой страницей надо было скрипт добавить в content_scripts.

```
"content_scripts":[
        {
           "matches": ["http://vk.com/*", "http://*.vk.com/*", "https://vk.com/*", "https://*.vk.com/*"],
            "js" :  [ "js/jquery.js" ,  "js/script.js" ],
            "run_at": "document_end"
    }
]
```

Как то так. Спасибо Qwertiy